# placing smaato ads in different positions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm starting to know smaato and I'm planning to shipping it with my first published app. I used the method in the documentation

```
 banner = [[SOMABannerView alloc] initWithDimension:kSOMAAdDimensionDefault];
 [[self view] addSubview:banner];
```

To create the banner and then place it in the main view. It appears nice and pretty in the top. The thing is, I want it to be presented in the bottom of the screen. I know it's best for advertising to go in the top, so it drives more user attention, but for this case I just need it in the bottom. I tried making a subview with a rect and adding the banner to the subview, but it still shows up in the top. I read trough the little documentation to find nothing.

Has anybody came up with this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, for some reason it didn't work last night but it does right now. For others with this same problem, the fix was putting a low subview and loading the banner there.

```
UIView *vista = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 380, 50)];
[vista addSubview:banner];
[[self view] addSubview:vista];
```